# Custom picker which can able to select two times at a time

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uidatepicker

How to design this screen in iOS.

[image]

It can select two times at a time, is it possible if so what is the approach?

Comment: Why not use UIPickerView with 6 cols?

Comment: @Harry already tried, but not able to scroll continuously(i.e, circular scroll)

Comment: http://viksiphoneblog.blogspot.hk/2010/12/circular-picker-view.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you @Sudhin Davis that was a nice idea, but finally i decided to continue without any change in UI. I found the solution from @Harry's comment. Here is what i did to fix it

```
let maxV = 25000
override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.pickerVIew.delegate = self
    self.pickerVIew.dataSource = self
    self.pickerViewLoaded(0, component: 0)
    self.pickerViewLoaded(0, component: 1)
    self.pickerViewLoaded(0, component: 3)
    self.pickerViewLoaded(0, component: 4)

}
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 6
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    if(component == 2 || component == 5)
    {
        return 2
    }
    else
    {
        return maxV
    }
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!
{
    if(component == 0 || component == 3)
    {
        return String(format: "%02d", (row%12)+1)
    }
    else if(component == 1 || component == 4)
    {

        return String(format: "%02d", (row%12)*5)
    }
    else
    {
        return row == 0 ? "AM" : "PM"
    }
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    self.pickerViewLoaded(row,component: component)
}
func pickerViewLoaded(row:Int,component:Int)
{
    var base12 = (maxV/2)-(maxV/2)%12;
    self.pickerVIew.selectRow(row%12+base12, inComponent: component, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope It is better to use tab bar type picker view where we can handle the start date and end date by 2 Different Buttons. I have shown a sample image. I hope you can understand from the image given.

When `starts` Button is selected the `UIDatePicker` will vary the start date `label` and when `ends` button is selected the `UIDatePicker` will vary the end date `label`.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom view that has 2 UIDatePickers and put them in a UIStackView also you can add labels above. Here is a sample view that does it:

```
class IntervalPickerView: BaseView {
@IBOutlet weak var startDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var endDatePicker: UIDatePicker!

weak var delegate: IntervalPickerDelegate?

override func postInit() {
    startDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    endDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
}

@objc func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker){
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let selectedTime = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    delegate?.didPickTime(selectedTime, isStart: sender == startDatePicker)
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot for it but didn't find any example for custom UIDatePicker as you are seeking but you can look into this [link](http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/ios-programming-recipe-9-adding-multiple-columns-to-uipickerview/) and create a picker of your own it will not be that specific date picker but it will be a picker view and you can code it as per your requirement.

[iOS Programming Recipe 9: Adding Multiple Columns to UIPickerView](http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/ios-programming-recipe-9-adding-multiple-columns-to-uipickerview/)

Comment: till now i am trying this only, but i have blocked by circular scroll of component in UIPickerviewController